# adding SALT to hash (crypt) function (clarification),few minor questions aswell

Tags: php, encryption, bcrypt

I've been studying/looking about on Google for TOO long and although I find many **so-so** tutorials, I'm wondering a bit about the "optional SALT" parameter in the  (crypt) function within PHP. I have too many tabs open and getting nowhere so, at this point, I figured id just ask for help.

As far as the salt, I read somewhere that if you don't add it, it will be added for you but that this is not good practice. I can't seem to find the "**why**" it's good/not good. How should this be handled?

I've read a few things here and there about randomizing salts but others say it doesn't matter...again, confusing.

Also I'm having problems checking against the stored data as well. Obviously if I do something like

```
crypt("pass string here",salt here);
```

ill get a random string for the pass....so on a user log in, then the value of

```
$_POST['the entered name/pass etc '];
```

and checking against the db value for that users pass would always equal to false. So then I suppose that id have to rehash /salt the pass given upon user entry and *then* test against what's on the db?

Also, I've read throughout the net (but at this point I'm confused) that somehow the salt is stored in the db? and it doesn't have to be hidden?

I can keep going on and on, just lost honestly, I think I've read too much and not sure how to proceed. At this point, What id REALLY prefer is a GOOD link with tutorial if anyone has those resources.

Comment: Unless you're using SSL, don't have your users send the password in cleartext. At a minimum, always use Javascript to hash it first client-side, preferably after sending their salt value down to them, possibly with a further one-time extra salt to defeat replay. If they turn Javascript off, you might warn them about the insecurity.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: If you're not using SSL, don't accept passwords, _period_.  Javascript crypto without SSL doesn't do any good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a secure random salt value when the user signs up, and store that salt in the database.

When the user logs in, fetch the salt and hash from the database, compute the hash of the password they typed using the original salt, and make sure the hash matches.

Also, don't use general-purpose hash algorithms (such as MD5 or SHA*); instead, use dedicated slow password-hashing algorithms, such as bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2.

Answer (score 0):

To maximize security, you never have a plaintext password in the database and leave it open to anyone who has/can get access to that database. So what you do is pick a predefined salt, take the user's desired password and encrypt it using the salt and a hash.

The salt is some extra random characters you add on to make the hashed password even more secure., you should keep track of this.

The hash then takes the salt + password and generates a random string based on it, such that you will always get that unique hash if you give it the same salt+password.

This seems like a fairly useful introduction to salting/hashing:

http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm